# open folder with ctl files in grads

Tags: grads

can you i'm having trouble opening multiple ctl files in grads.

The folder contains 20 ctl files and i'd like not to open them one by one.

Unfortunately `open pathfolder` does not work. 
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your ctl files are of the form sample1.ctl, sample2.ctl, 
sample3.ctl... sample9.ctl.  The
script would look something like

```
i = 1
while ( i <= 9 )
  'open sample'%i
  'd u'
  'd v'
  'reinit'
  i = i + 1
endwhile
```

Note that if you don't "reinit" you'll have to specify the variable from 
each ctl file (e.g.,
instead of just 'd u' it would be 'd u.1' for the first file, 'd u.2' 
for the second, and so on.
Also, without a reinit you could run out of memory.  Also, you might 
have to add some
if/then lines for cases like "sample01.ctl", e.g., "open sample0'%i" if 
i is less than 10.
Hope that works.